# What does the woman say in the movie?

Tags: american-english, conversation, cinema, listening

What does the woman say in the movie?

The link to the specified section of the movie:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XHAEckAKxeEGyF2hQ8juhA5ewshXEhCo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The video clip needs to be longer, to provide more context clues. I understand “*Oh, um. We're letting (?) the kids ? everyone ? space*”? That last word is especially difficult, I reckon it has been cut off too early.

Comment: Thank you @Mari-LouA I made it longer: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VlNywQ7mpu7dBiZD6OayN4m7WZOyDg9r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, @niamulbengali I have seen it. But I think she says another thing. As Mari-Lou A said, she says something like this: Oh, um. We're letting the kids have their own special (the last words are the things that I think).

Comment: ... *special* is a strong contender. But it's still difficult for me to fully understand. Maybe you could [**edit** your post](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/559190/edit), include the longer clip and write the fragments you have understood so far. Be warned, your question could be closed because EL&U is not a free [transcription service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(service)), and your question may be of very limited use and interest to future visitors.

Comment: You're right @Mari-LouA Do you know any transcription service to get help?

Comment: This is the Internet, I'm sure your Googling powers are as good, if not better than mine. YouTube also provides subtitles, or look for the movie script of Taken.

Comment: This runs pretty far afield of what ELU is about, I'm afraid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves a particular instance of pronouncing a particular word—and therefore is not likely to be of interest to anyone but the question's poster. This is another instance where "Too localized" would be a much more useful and accurate close option than "Please include the research..." since, obviously, lack of research isn't the problem here.

Comment: "Oh, um, we're letting the kids **have their own** space." The mom is saying she is not sure where a gift would go, as the kids are running around by themselves, only loosely supervised.

Comment: Thank you @YosefBaskin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She says:

Oh, um. We're letting the kids have their own space. Ya could put if right there with the others.